# Are hats working properly?

Tags: support, comments, winter-bash-2012

I have commented 5 times today but still have not got the 5x comments hat (Howdy Pardner). Is it supposed to be comments on your question/answer and not you personally commenting?

Comment: I sense we'll have a lot of comments, today, if this hat subtitle isn't made more clear...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Description of [Howdy Pardner](http://winterba.sh/howdy-pardner)

> ### Howdy Pardner
>
> leave 5 comments **with a score of 1 or more**

So you need leave 5 comments with a score of 1 or more. Simple.

Comment: Most excellent. Pip pip. (Wasn't 100% obvious)

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out how to put the hat on XD

Comment: I didn't even realize you could do that!

Comment: @darryn.ten - Yup I did it. :) But use [`@Reply`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/187824) to reply anyone. So that he/she can get notification.

Comment: @hims056 thanks! I learn something everyday here

Comment: @darryn.ten Go into your profile and click on the hats link, then select your hat :)