# Howdy Pardner?

Tags: support, feedback, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are hats working properly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159246/are-hats-working-properly)

The hats are great! I've earning a few today but I spotted `Howdy Pardner` hasn't been awarded on SO? According to my comment activity I have left 8 today and 5th being over 3 hours ago, the only reason I ask is the other hats I earned today were award pretty quickly.

Well maybe not the only reason I ask *~Constantinopolitan ;)*

Awesome idea!

Comment: Are you sure that all those comments have upvotes?

Comment: @balpha I wasn't aware +1 was part of the spec, it just says `5 comments`

Comment: It says "leave 5 comments with a score of 1 or more" in the full description. I'll clarify the short form.

Comment: D'oh now I see if you click on the hat you get more info, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **balpha** kindly mentioned in the comments above: it's not just 5 comments, it's 5 *nonzero scored* comments. Which means you need 5 of your comments to be at >= +1 for it to trigger.

This will be made more clear on the site page. Thanks for helping us make this better!